# Program "freezing" after pressing start button Java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, cardlayout

I'm trying to implement a start button that when pressed brings the user to another page where you can play a simple game. However, each time I press the start button, the program does not run correctly and shows an unplayable game. The game should have moving platforms (which works in SimpleWindow) but does not work after a button is pressed in FrontPage. How do I switch panels so the program runs correctly in both?

Start Page

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.*;

public class FrontPage extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private JButton start;
    private JButton rules;



    public FrontPage() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        start = new JButton("Start");
        rules = new JButton("Rules");

        add(start);
        add(rules);
        start.addActionListener(this);  
        rules.addActionListener(this);  

    }  

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {  

        SimpleWindow window = new SimpleWindow();
        add(window);

        if (e.getSource() == start){    
            JFrame w = new JFrame("Simple Window");
            w.setBounds(100, 100, 1000, 600);
            w.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            //SimpleWindow panel = new SimpleWindow();
            SimpleWindow panel = window;
            w.addKeyListener(panel);
            w.add(panel);
            w.setResizable(true);
            w.setVisible(true);

            repaint();
        } else if (e.getSource() == start){  


        }
    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        Font f1 = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, (width / 18));

        g.setFont(f1);
        g.drawString("SQUARED", (int) ((int) width / 2.5), (int) (2.5 * height / 8));

        // b.setBounds(50,100,100,100);

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame a = new JFrame("Squared");
        a.setBounds(100, 100, 1000, 600);
        a.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        FrontPage panel = new FrontPage();
        // w.addActionListener(panel);
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        a.add(panel);
        a.setResizable(true);
        a.setVisible(true);

        //panel.run();
    }

}
```

Program that should run

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleWindow extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
    public static final int DRAWING_WIDTH = 800;
    public static final int DRAWING_HEIGHT = 600;

    private Runner runner;
    private MovingPlatform platform, platform2, platform3, platform4, platform5;

    private boolean leftKeyPressed, rightKeyPressed, upKeyPressed;
    private int width = getWidth();
    private int height = getHeight();

    public SimpleWindow() {
        super();
        runner = new Runner(380, 0);
        platform = new MovingPlatform("bricks.png", 200, 500, 200, 50);
        platform2 = new MovingPlatform("bricks.png", 600, 400, 200, 50);
        platform3 = new MovingPlatform("bricks.png", 200, 300, 200, 50);
        platform4 = new MovingPlatform("bricks.png", 400, 200, 200, 50);
        platform5 = new MovingPlatform("bricks.png", 100, 100, 200, 50);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); // Call JPanel's paintComponent method to paint the background

        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        double ratioX = (double) width / DRAWING_WIDTH;
        double ratioY = (double) height / DRAWING_HEIGHT;

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        AffineTransform at = g2.getTransform();
        g2.scale(ratioX, ratioY);

        platform.draw(g, this);
        platform2.draw(g, this);
        platform3.draw(g, this);
        platform4.draw(g, this);
        platform5.draw(g, this);
        runner.draw(g, this);

        g2.setTransform(at);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            leftKeyPressed = true;
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            rightKeyPressed = true;
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            runner.jump();
            upKeyPressed = true;
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            leftKeyPressed = false;
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            rightKeyPressed = false;
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            upKeyPressed = false;
        }
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            // MAKE A CHANGE
            // change runner
            if (leftKeyPressed) {
                runner.walk(-1);
            } else if (rightKeyPressed) {
                runner.walk(1);
            } else if (upKeyPressed) {
                runner.jump();
            }
            //System.out.println("before fall");
            runner.fall(platform, platform2, platform3, platform4, platform5);
            // runner.fall(platform2);
            checkrunner();
            checkplatform();
            checkplatform2();
            checkplatform3();
            checkplatform4();
            checkplatform5();
            // change platform
            platform.moveByAmount(-6, 0);
            platform2.moveByAmount(-6, 0);
            platform3.moveByAmount(-6, 0);
            platform4.moveByAmount(-6, 0);
            platform5.moveByAmount(-6, 0);
            // SHOW THE CHANGE
            repaint();

            // WAIT
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    public void checkrunner() {
        int x = runner.getX() + runner.getWidth() / 2;
        int y = runner.getY() + runner.getHeight() / 2;
        if (x < 0 || x > DRAWING_WIDTH /* || y < 0 */|| y > DRAWING_HEIGHT )
            runner = new Runner(380, 0);
    }

    public void checkplatform() {
        int x = platform.getX() + platform.getWidth() / 2;
        int y = platform.getY() + platform.getHeight() / 2;
        if (x < 0 || x > DRAWING_WIDTH || y < 0 || y > DRAWING_HEIGHT)
            platform = new MovingPlatform("bricks.png", 600, randomNumY(), 200, 50);

    }

    public int randomNumY() {
        int numY = (int) Math.floor((Math.random() * 8)) * 100;

        return numY;
    }

    public void checkplatform2() {

        int x2 = platform2.getX() + platform2.getWidth() / 2;
        int y2 = platform2.getY() + platform2.getHeight() / 2;
        if (x2 < 0 || x2 > DRAWING_WIDTH || y2 < 0 || y2 > DRAWING_HEIGHT) {
            platform2 = new MovingPlatform("bricks.png", 600, randomNumY(), 200, 50);
        }

    }

    public void checkplatform3() {
        int x2 = platform3.getX() + platform3.getWidth() / 2;
        int y2 = platform3.getY() + platform3.getHeight() / 2;
        if (x2 < 0 || x2 > DRAWING_WIDTH || y2 < 0 || y2 > DRAWING_HEIGHT) {
            platform3 = new MovingPlatform("bricks.png", 600, randomNumY(), 200, 50);
        }

    }

    public void checkplatform4() {
        int x2 = platform4.getX() + platform4.getWidth() / 2;
        int y2 = platform4.getY() + platform4.getHeight() / 2;
        if (x2 < 0 || x2 > DRAWING_WIDTH || y2 < 0 || y2 > DRAWING_HEIGHT) {
            platform4 = new MovingPlatform("bricks.png", 600, randomNumY(), 200, 50);
        }
    }

    public void checkplatform5() {
        int x2 = platform5.getX() + platform5.getWidth() / 2;
        int y2 = platform5.getY() + platform5.getHeight() / 2;
        if (x2 < 0 || x2 > DRAWING_WIDTH || y2 < 0 || y2 > DRAWING_HEIGHT) {
            platform5 = new MovingPlatform("bricks.png", 600, randomNumY(), 200, 50);
        }

    }

    public void makeChange() {


    }

    public void showChange() {

        repaint();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame w = new JFrame("Simple Window");
        w.setBounds(100, 100, 1000, 600);
        w.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        SimpleWindow panel = new SimpleWindow();
        w.addKeyListener(panel);
        w.add(panel);
        w.setResizable(true);
        w.setVisible(true);

        panel.run();
    }
}
```

Expected result: moving platforms and runner

Actual result: program "frozen"

Comment: essentially, what you have in run() should be in a swing timer

Comment: where are the duplicates